# PHP Array Comparison without caring order,count & Display Count

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have 2 arrays named

```
$user = array("Joomla","Java");
```

and

```
$cpny= array("PHP","Java","Joomla");
```

I want to compare this arrays without caring the **Order** and **Count** (no: of elements) and also want to Display the **Count** (no: of elements matched) after the Comparison.

*Thanks in Advance*

I have some more doubts and i post along with this Question..

These above 2 arrays are Belonging to the Skills of a Candidate and Required Skill for a Job that Posted by a Company(My Project is a Job Portal). To select candidates,company needs to search candidates with required skills.So above comparison take places and the output will be 0,1,2,...etc.(no: of elements matched).assume that value is 3

Now i want to select candidates whose skill is perfectly matched with required skill(comparison o/p =3),and display it in top of the table,then 2(comparison o/p =2) and then 1(comparison o/p =1)

Comment: [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) perhaps?

Comment: Before ask the question have you searched???

Comment: duellsy and Mahmood Rehman gave the answer! what did you learn.

Comment: Thanks for Ur instant reply user2727841 . Im beginner in PHP .i searched in the internet and i get some solutions but none of them achieved what i assumed. and i have to complete a work on today itself.so there not enough time to spend on the internet by searching this particular question...anyway the answer given by duellsy and Mahmood Rehman is Correct ...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a specific method in PHP to achieve this, see [`php_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

In your case, you could do something like

```
$similar = array_intersect($user, $cpny);
$similar_count = sizeof($similar);

echo($similar_count);
```

Comment: Yes the Goal is achieved. Thanks a lot Bro.